# Authzforce permission creation issue

Tags: fiware, authzforce

I want to have permission to get entity by id, but this question also apply to any route where some variable is needed.

I was not able to find some example of this, and not sure what syntax i should use for it.

Because now when i execute get i get refused by authzforce because he read url like 
`v2/entities/Test` and compare it with its permissions and expected there is no permission.

So what i have to change in order for this to work, i try with
v2/entities/{id}
v2/entities/{{id}}
and some more.

Any suggestion would help

[image]

Comment: This is a screenshot from the IdM. So you have to check what the IdM does with your input and what it actually sends to the AuthzForce server. AuthzForce takes whatever policy the IdM sends to it. I am not sure the IdM can convert template or wildcard parameters in the resource URL like this to proper XACML policy syntax for AuthzForce. You should ask the IdM dev team (which I am not part of) if they actually support this (or check their source code).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check with them.